# Ошибка при добавлении новой сущности. Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Привет всем, столкнулся с ошибкой при добавлении новой сущности в базу данных.
Ниже привожу код сущностей/код метода где создается сущность/код метода ответственного за добавление.

Сущности:

```
public sealed class Lot : Entity
{
    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool InCredit { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(1), Range(1, 10)]
    public int PhaseNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal DesiredPrice { get; set; }

    public Guid? AcceptedBetId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExpirationDateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public Car Car { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Bet> Bets { get; set; }

    public Lot()
    {
        Bets = new List<Bet>();
    }
}

public sealed class Bet : Entity
{
    [Required, Range(0.0, double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public int BetNumber { get; set; }

    public Lot Lot { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Участок кода где я создаю новую сущность, и вызываю метод сохранения:

```
Lot lot;
using (LotsManager lotsManager = new LotsManager())
{
     lot = await lotsManager.GetLotAsync(model.LotId);
}

User user;
using (UserManager userManager = new UserManager())
{
      user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(model.UserInfoId);
}

var bet = new Bet
{
      Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
      Price = model.Price,
      CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
      BetNumber = lastBetNumber + 1,
      Lot = lot,
      User = user
 };

 await _betsManager.SaveBetAsync(bet);
```

Метод который ответственен а добавление данных в БД.

```
protected async Task Save<T>(T entity) where T : Entity
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                var dbEntity = await _context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == entity.Id);

                _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
                _context.Entry(entity).State = dbEntity != null ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                dbContextTransaction?.Commit();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                dbContextTransaction?.Rollback();

                var error = ex.EntityValidationErrors.First().ValidationErrors.First();
                throw new InvalidModelException(error.ErrorMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dbContextTransaction?.Rollback();

                throw new InvalidDbOperationException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Собственно сом код ошибки. Она возникает на строке (_context.Set().Attach(entity)).

> Attaching an entity of type 'WebCar.Domain.Entities.Lot' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Я пробовал использовать разные приемы, но ничего не получилось

```
_context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
or
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Спасибо всем кто откликнется. Сам я джун, так что особо не судите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема кроется в методе:

```
protected async Task Save<T>(T entity) where T : Entity
{
    using (var dbContextTransaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var dbEntity = await _context
                           .Set<T>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == entity.Id);

            _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
            _context.Entry(entity).State = 
                 dbEntity != null 
                 ? EntityState.Modified 
                 : EntityState.Added;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            dbContextTransaction?.Commit();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex) { /* ... */ }
        catch (Exception ex) { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

1. У тебя есть объект `entity`, передаваемый через параметр в метод.
2. Внутри метода ты снова *пытаешься* получить этот же объект в `dbEntity`
3. У тебя получается два объекта, с одинаковыми `primary key`, которые нужно отслеживать, от этого и падает ошибка.

Как исправить:

- При получении `dbEntity` использовать `AsNoTracking`, метод `AsNoTracking()` применяется к набору `IQueryable`, это значит что Entity Framework не будет отслеживать изменения полученных объектов.
- Попытаться получить объект до открытия транзакции, просто открыв контекст и заполнив переменную внутри мода перед открытием транзакции, причем контекст в котором получаешь этот объект - потом закрыть, ведь тебе важен сам объект был или нет, чтобы поставить статус `EntityState.Modified` если был или `EntityState.Added` если не было.

Comment: Пробовал ставить `AsNoTracking` Увы все та же ошибка.
Но, все остальные эндпоинты работаю как надо!
Только в это случае с лотом и ставкой проблемы.

Comment: @BogdanStefanjuk, певое - получи `dbEntity` через `AsNoTracking`, если  `dbEntity == null` тогда делай `Attach(entity)`, в противном случае не нужно. Попробуй.

Comment: [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/f1t3en)
Скин того как я сделал и отметил на нем место где дропает ошибку.
Все на том же Attach(entity)

Comment: @BogdanStefanjuk, получается он у тебя уже отслеживается... либо элементы, вложенные в этот объект. Если ты его заполняешь объектами, полученными из контекста, то в тех местах тоже `AsNoTracking` нужно.

Comment: [google drive with screens](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxs17Nthz35gV2ZxYmVGUXk0bzQ)
Извините что дальше отвлекаю, но ничего не получается, оставил ссылку на диск, со скринами кода и внутренностей сущности. Возможно это прольет свет на ситуацию =)

Comment: добавил в диск еще скрин с рабочим участком кода

Comment: @BogdanStefanjuk, получается, что вы `lot` из базы берете, и он отслеживается EF, поэтому ошибка, нужно, чтобы не отслеживался. А тот скрин, где написано *Тут все ОК*, там вы его руками создаете, поэтому и нет там ошибки.

Comment: Просто в том же лоте(рабочий код) есть сущность пользователя, которою мы достаем полностью и там нету конфликта клбчей при сейве

Comment: Просто на сущность User не ругается, хотя отношение там такое же как и Lot до Bet